# jQuery $( "" ).text(); to simply identify text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the following jQuery:

```
$("TD.info > font").text();
```

when the following HTML is on a page:

```
<td class="info">
  <font>
    3001474535
  </font>
</td>
```

I thought that by modifying the same code with the thought of looking for a TD which contains the text "Example Data" and then following that is a td with the class results.

```
$( "TD.info:contains('Example Data:') > TD.results" ).text();
```

to find the following HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="info">Example Data:</td>
  <td class="result">12345</td>
</tr>
```

I want to identity that number, 12345. My problem is that it is not the first instance of td class="info" and td class="results". My code doesn't seem to be working and ALSO one thing to point out is that it is not the first instance of the pattern td.info > td.result that is why I was using the contains "Example Data" because that is unique.

Comment: Are you or is anyone aware of a straight javascript solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it won't work because the `td` elements are siblings

One solution could be to find the `td` with class `info` and text `Example Data:` then find its next sibling with class results

```
$( "TD.info:contains('Example Data:')" ).next('TD.results').text();
```

or find the `tr` having a `td` with class `info` and text `Example Data:` then find its child `td` with class `results`

```
$( "tr:has(TD.info:contains('Example Data:')) > TD.results" ).text();
```

Comment: There's also the general sibling operator `~` - `"TD.info:contains('foo') ~ TD.results"`

Comment: Are you or is anyone aware of a straight javascript solution?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$( "TD.info:contains('Example Data:')").siblings("TD.results").text();
```

The problem with your code is that, `TD.results` is not the child element of `TD.info`.

You can use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) for your need